# why replace method is not working with variable in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

`"cos²+cos²+sin²".replace(/²/g,"2")` is working fine, superscript ² is replaced with 2 as

```
cos2+cos2+sin2 .
```

But with variable it is not working

```
var str=document.getElementById('result_txta');// where result_txta is an ID of textarea
var s=str.value.replace(/²/g,"2");
```

Comment: var str="cos²+cos²+sin²";
str  = str.replace(/²/g,"2");

Comment: @Mr.Smee sorry, previously I didn't specify my question properly. Now I edited the question

Comment: can you make a fiddle

Answer (score 2):

`replace()` returns the result, it doesn't change the original one.

```
var str="cos²+cos²+sin²";
str = str.replace(/²/g,"2");
```